# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition error

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, table

I have a table, with two foreign keys defined on two columns of that table. The problem is that, when I insert the values from SQL Server, I get the following error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Please see the below image for the definition of the table. Can you please tell me why the value is not getting inserted?

[image: Table Image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the INSERT statement, too.

Comment: @MichaelGreen: But I was getting this error only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not showing us what you're doing - but based on the table structure, this is what you *should* do:

- create an `INSERT` statement that **explicitly** lists the columns it will insert into - assuming that `ID` might be an `IDENTITY` column that you don't want / can't insert into
- define the exact number of values to fill into these columns

So your `INSERT` statement should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Post (cat_id, ngo_id, title, description, active)
VALUES (42, 4711, 'Some title', 'Some description', 1)
```

What you should definitely get in the habits of **avoiding** is using `INSERT INTO dbo.tblPost` *without* explicitly defining the list of column to insert into. This is just a recipe for disaster, as soon as you change your table definition, all your existing `INSERT`s will break since they don't match the table definition anymore.

Therefore: **always** explicitly define the list of columns that an `INSERT` statement should fill data into!

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post on the topic:
[Bad habits to kick: using SELECT * / omit the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: I have two FK column in the tbl_Post. will it not afftect the table ?

Comment: @codeOholic: no - you just need to insert **valid** values for those two foreign keys....

Comment: Message from the future - Aaron B's blog post URI changed, in 2019 it's here:    https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list

Comment: @charlesross: thanks - updated my link